# train a model with djl

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, djl

Good evening !
I'm starting with DJL.
My code source is here https://github.com/ngandji/green_anthill.git
someone can tell what is wrong in my code!
I learn with this https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/tree/master/jupyter/tutorial tutorial.
the compilation works correctly but I'm getting this error when I try to run.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'C:\Users\Green\.djl.ai\mxnet\1.8.0-mkl-win-x86_64\mxnet.dll':
The specified module could not be found.

The specified module could not be found.

Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\Green\.djl.ai\mxnet\1.8.0-mkl-win-x86_64\mxnet.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\Green\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DJLHelloWord\target\classes;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.3\spring-boot-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.10\logback-classic-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.10\logback-core-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.1\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.33\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.1\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.1\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.1\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.15\spring-web-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.15\spring-beans-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.15\spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.15\spring-aop-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.15\spring-context-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.15\spring-expression-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.5.0\commons-cli-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.33\slf4j-simple-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.33\slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\api\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.9.0\jna-5.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\basicdataset\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\basicdataset-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-csv\1.8\commons-csv-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\model-zoo\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\model-zoo-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-model-zoo\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\mxnet-model-zoo-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-engine\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-native-auto\1.8.0\mxnet-native-auto-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.15\spring-core-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.15\spring-jcl-5.3.15.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:301) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:461) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:570) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
    at ai.djl.mxnet.jna.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:73) ~[mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.mxnet.jna.JnaUtils.<clinit>(JnaUtils.java:69) ~[mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.mxnet.engine.MxEngine.newInstance(MxEngine.java:52) ~[mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.mxnet.engine.MxEngineProvider.getEngine(MxEngineProvider.java:40) ~[mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.engine.Engine.getEngine(Engine.java:177) ~[api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:132) ~[api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.Model.newInstance(Model.java:71) ~[api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at ai.djl.Model.newInstance(Model.java:60) ~[api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.green.DJLHelloWord.service.training.TrainModelService.trainMnist(TrainModelService.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.green.DJLHelloWord.controller.ModelController.trainMnist(ModelController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\Green\.djl.ai\mxnet\1.8.0-mkl-win-x86_64\mxnet.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\Green\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DJLHelloWord\target\classes;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.3\spring-boot-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.10\logback-classic-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.10\logback-core-1.2.10.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.1\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.33\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.1\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.1\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.1\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.1\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.15\spring-web-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.15\spring-beans-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.15\spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.15\spring-aop-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.15\spring-context-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.15\spring-expression-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.6.3\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.56\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.56.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.5.0\commons-cli-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-simple\1.7.33\slf4j-simple-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.33\slf4j-api-1.7.33.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\api\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\api-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.9\gson-2.8.9.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.9.0\jna-5.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\basicdataset\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\basicdataset-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-csv\1.8\commons-csv-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\model-zoo\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\model-zoo-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-model-zoo\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\mxnet-model-zoo-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-engine\0.16.0-SNAPSHOT\mxnet-engine-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\ai\djl\mxnet\mxnet-native-auto\1.8.0\mxnet-native-auto-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.15\spring-core-5.3.15.jar;C:\Users\Green\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.15\spring-jcl-5.3.15.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1119) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:275) ~[jna-5.9.0.jar:5.9.0 (b0)]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

DJL on windows requires Visual C++ Redistributable Packages, you can install [Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Packages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and reboot your machine.

See: https://docs.djl.ai/docs/development/troubleshooting.html#13-unsatisfiedlinkerror-issue

Comment: thank you! I switched to Ubuntu. now my program compiles